# Prevent href="#" loosing focus (scrolling up to top of the page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if its possible to prevent the empty `href` link to scroll up on top of the page when that link is clicked.

For instance I have:

```
<a href="#">Hello world</a>
```

If the "**Hello world**" link is lets say on middle of the page and I click it (if its in this form like i stated above), when I click this link, my url would look like this:

```
myurl.com/#
```

However, what happens is that each time this link is clicked as empty `href` tag, my page scrolls up to top, and I don't want that to happen, it's very annoying and I wanna remove that. Is there any way for me to do that via JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: If a link doesn't go somewhere, don't use a link.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you could prevent the default action of the click event like this:

```
$("a[href='#']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

That way the URL won't change if you click on a link that has `#` as the `href` attribute, so there will be no scrolling.